# Using regex to limit account IDs input in a field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a form on a website using Angular 1.6 and one of the fields allows users to input account IDs on which an action should be performed. (There are actually several of these forms all powered by the same controller.)

Users are asked to separate the IDs by any non-alphanumeric character.

On some instances of these forms, however, I need to restrict the number of IDs that can be specified.  (All IDs fit the pattern `[a-z0-9]`.)  I have gotten close to what I need with the following RegEx pattern and ng-pattern.  The regexp is stored in a var in app.js and the var is referenced in the HTML:

```
new RegExp(`^(?:(?=([a-z0-9]+))\\1[^a-zA-Z0-9]*){1,${maxSites}}$`);
```

Unfortunately, this also matches commas, whitespace, etc. after an account ID.  For instance, my RegEx matches `foobar,` ("foobar" followed by a comma and a space) when it shouldn't.

Here is a table showing of what I expect a working RegEx to match based on `maxSites`:

```
Input                       | Max | Max 2 | Max 3
foobar                      | yes |  yes  | yes  
foobar,                     | no  |  no   | no  
foobar,                     | no  |  no   | no  
foobar,bizbaz               | no  |  yes  | yes  
foobar, bizbaz1             | no  |  yes  | yes  
foobar bizbaz1              | no  |  yes  | yes  
foobar, bizbaz1,            | no  |  no   | no  
foobar, bizbaz1, binbong2   | no  |  no   | yes
```

Is there a way to do this with RegExp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.
^([a-z0-9]+){1}(,[a-z0-9]+){0,(MAX-1)}
This site https://regexr.com/ lets you test out the strings you want to test and you can see if it matches. The idea is the first group can't have a comma and can only have one alphanumeric string. The second group includes the comma first so you can not have a trailing comma and can repeat either 0 to MAX-1. I hope this helps.

Comment: This was nearly exactly what I was looking for.  I made a slight change to the RegExp you provided just because I didn't want the comma to be the only delimiter that the user could use.  The final RegExp looks like this:
`^([a-z0-9]+){1}([\W]+[a-z0-9]+){0,4}$`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have other more compelling reasons to use a regex, I'd prefer validating this using a custom validation function.  It really looks like you're trying to split a string on and then verify the number of (non-empty) elements is less than or equal to a number.  This is a good time to use [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and a bad time to use regex.  Here's a simple function that will validate the form of your string:

```
function isValidAction(str, max) {
    if (!str || !max)
        return false;

    //split the string by non-alphanumeric
    var actions = str.split(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/);

    //validate length
    var valid = actions.length <= max;
    //validate every element has non-empty content
    valid = valid && actions.every(function(a) {
        return a.length > 0;
    });
    return valid;
}
```

Then, just hook it up manually with `ng-change` and use stuff like [`form.element.$setValidity()`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setValidity) to manually validate your custom logic.

[Demo on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2AOei6HGu5TVqyVlBL5w?p=preview)

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer to a similar question...  I really feel that this would be the best practice for solving this issue.  It is elegant and follows all of Angular's best practices.  The only reason that I did not mark it as the accepted answer is that the question posed was "is there a way to do this with RegExp" and this answer doesn't directly speak to that.  (It does, however, offer a better alternative.)

Comment: No worries.  Later, when you get the privilege to upvote posts, you can note the fact that this answer is helpful with an upvote (and leaving the other answer accepted).